# Restrict express route access without authenticating users

Tags: express, authentication, middleware

I'm new in the web dev world. I'm building a rest API in express and I was hoping you guys could point out best practice for the following. I am working on a store that will be both web and mobile. The users will never login so I can't use standard authentication. I don't see an issue with leaving get request for products unprotected, but I'm unsure how to secure the post method that will update the database with sales information. Is it best to hardcode the secret into the app / client website?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standard web api (not core) and you've created the project using the Web API template via Visual Studio you probably have an AccountController. You can use it to create Users. You can then decorate either entire Controllers with `[Authorize]` or just the methods you want to "protect".

Just remember to obtain the Token (by calling `/Token`) passing the Credentials you've created in order to access the methods/controllers with `[Authorize]`.